# There is no WPF designer and no projects in Visual Studio 2022 solution

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2022

I'm starting to learn WPF through a course on [Udemy](https://www.udemy.com/), and when I open a new "WPF Application" template there is only a `MainWindow.xaml` and `MainWindow.xaml.cs` file, but no designer and no projects in the solution.

[image]

I've been googling to no avail. I'm not real savvy with all this as I've just begun in visual studio. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It would be good to know the process or exact Udemy course you followed to generate the steps to create your visual studio solution - as they should almost always have a project in the solution by default.

Answer (score 0):

When you open the xaml file you will see some header lines and below you will find something like  ...  or another container.
Your code window probably overlaps the "Design Window".
Hover the mouse over the upper or bottom end of this xaml code window until you see a "double arrow" allowing you to change the height of the code window.
When shrinking the code window the design window comes into view.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your solution doesn't contain any projects (hence the **Solution Explorer** is showing `'Solution WpfApp18' (0 projects)`, perhaps you deleted it or removed from the solution it by mistake. By default, WPF solutions should have at least one WPF project on creation.

Visual Studio will not show the designer if you open `xaml` files individually outside a WPF project.

To fix, you will either need to:

- Add a new project to your solution, or...
- Add an existing project to your solution, or...
- Simply create a new WPF solution

Since you are a beginner and to get something working quickly in the short term, I'd recommend adding a new project to your solution for now. Right click on the Solution `'WpfApp18' (0 projects)` in the **Solution Explorer** and select `Add --> New Project...`

[image: Add a new project step 1]

In the Add New Project window, enter `wpf` into the search window and you have multiple options, but I've highlighted two options in the screenshot with red:

[image: Add a new project step 2]

The top option will create a .NET 6 or above WPF project , the bottom option will create a .NET framework 4.x.x project or below. The choice depends on the hardware you are targeting and which features you need.

Once you have added the new project, you should now see a new project within your solution and you may now open `MainWindow.xaml` which will open the designer.

If this still fails to open the designer, there is some [anecdotal evidence](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Creating-a-new-project-creates-a-solutio/1428512) that deleting the path `C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet` can resolve the problem - be aware of any data that may be lost by doing so.

[image: New Project created]

Comment: When I do that it just doubles the first 2 files (MainWindow.xaml and MainWindow.xaml.cs) but still does not create a project in the solution.

Comment: It sounds like there are hidden issues that require more information to solve this problem. It may be machine related or file permission related. May I suggest you click on the "Send Feedback" button on the top right of the Visual Studio window and create an account on https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/ to send more information to Microsoft about the problem.

Comment: It seems that this question on the developer community closely resembles your issue https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Creating-a-new-project-creates-a-solutio/1428512?q=no+project